# How to sign in to Azure Repos in VSCode GitLens

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, azure-repos, gitlens

I've used VSCode [Gitlens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) for git actions for repositories hosted on Github. But now, my projects are hosted on Azure Repos, and I cannot sign in to [Gitlens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) as it always shows the "Sign in with Github" option.
Can anyone suggest to me how to sign in to Azure Repos in VScode Gitlens extension?

P.S: I see the option of "Clone in VSCode" in Azure repos but I don't want to clone it again as I've already cloned it to my local.
[image]

Comment: *Git* literally has no sign-in option at all. This must be coming from VSCode or some extension.

Comment: @torek that's what I'm saying, VSCode Gitlens extension doesn't provide an option to sign in with Azure Repos.